# SSL configuration in Jboss 7.1 - java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, jboss7.x

I am configuring SSL for JBOSS 7.1 in a linux server. I created the key and csr following commands

```
openssl genrsa -out app.key -des 2048

openssl req -new -key app.key -out appCert.csr
```

I registered the certificate to entrust and received the root, chain and server certificate. The server certificate is stored in a file cert.crt

In JBOSS 7.1 standalone.xml, I modified the connector tag as below.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
    <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
    <connector name="https" scheme="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" socket-binding="https" enable-lookups="false" secure="true">
        <ssl name="APP-ssl" password="abc123" certificate-key-file="/app/JBoss-7.1/standalone/configuration/ssl/app.key" certificate-file="/app/JBoss-7.1/standalone/configuration/ssl/cert.crt"/>
</subsystem>
```

When i start the jboss server, I am getting the below error message.

ERROR [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory] (MSC service thread 1-2) Failed to load keystore type JKS with path /app/JBoss-7.1/standalone/configuration/ssl/app.key due to Invalid keystore format: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format

The same error occurs when i place the chain certificate also. Please help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [JBoss HTTPS connector documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/config/ssl.html), the certificate-key-file attribute should be pointing to a keystore, not a key.  So you will need to import that key into a JKS keystore.  There are examples on how to do that in the [JBoss SSL Configuration documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/ssl-howto.html).

Answer (score 0):

Change **native=true** in subsystem tag.

If you generate from OpenSSL tool, you need to enable native=true in Jboss 7.1.1

Check [**here**](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/SSL+setup+guide)